# Erlang sumif function

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to make a `sumif` function in Erlang that would return a sum of all elements in a list if the predicate function evaluates to true. Here is what I have:

```
sumif(_, []) -> undefined;
sumif(Fun, [H|T]) -> case Fun(H) of
                       true -> H + sumif(Fun, T);
                       false -> sumif(Fun, T)
                     end.
```

I also implemented my own pos function which returns true if a number is greater than 0 and false otherwise:

```
pos(A) -> A > 0.
```

I tried using `pos` with `sumif` but I'm getting this error:

```
exception error: bad function pos
```

Why is this happening? Is it because of my `sumif` function or `pos`? I have tested `pos` on its own and it seems to work just fine.

Edit: It might be because how I'm calling the function. This is how I'm currently calling it: `hi:sumif(pos,[-1,1,2,-3]).` Where `hi` is my module name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it because of my sumif function or pos?

It's because of `sumif`. You should return `0` when an empty list is passed, as it'll be called from the 2nd clause when `T` is `[]`:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

sumif(_, []) -> 0;
sumif(Fun, [H|T]) -> case Fun(H) of
                       true -> H + sumif(Fun, T);
                       false -> sumif(Fun, T)
                     end.

pos(A) -> A > 0.
```

Test:

```
1> c(a).
{ok,a}
2> a:sumif(fun a:pos/1, [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4]).
6
```

Comment: Thank you. It's also because the way I called the `pos` function is wrong too. Just learned something new!

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions make things far simpler:

```
sumif(F, L) ->
    lists:sum([X || X <- L, F(X)]).
```

[Dobert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320615/dogbert)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36963321/49197) is of cousrse right, problem is your sum for empty list.

If your concern is performance a little bit you should stick to tail recursive solution (in this case it matter because there is not `lists:reverse/1` involved).

```
sumif(F, L) ->
    sumif(F, L, 0).

sumif(F, [], Acc) when is_function(F, 1) -> Acc;
sumif(F, [H|T], Acc) ->
    New = case F(H) of
            true  -> H+Acc;
            false -> Acc
        end,
    sumif(F, T, New).
```

Ways how to make correct function for first parameter:

```
F1 = fun pos/1,     % inside module where pos/1 defined
F2 = fun xyz:pos/1, % exported function from module xyz (hot code swap works)
N = 0,
F3 = fun(X) -> X > N end, % closure
% test it
true = lists:all(fun(F) -> is_function(F, 1) end, [F1, F2, F3]).
```

Answer (score 0):

There has tow error in your code:
1. `sumif(_, []) -> undefined;` should return `0`, not `undefined`.
2. when you pass `pos(A) -> A > 0.` to `sumif/2`,you should use `fun pos/1`, please read http://erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/funs.html#id59138

```
sumif(F, L) ->
    lists:foldl(fun(X, Sum) when F(X) -> Sum+X; (_) -> Sum end, 0, L).
```

You can use `lists:foldl`.